# How to plot the region of x>0 where x is the root of an equation?

Tags: plotting

If x is one of the root of ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+d=0, how to plot the region of x>0 using

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{}, {a, -0.25, 0.25}, {b, -0.25, 0.25},FrameLabel -> Automatic], {{c, 1}, -1, 1},{{d,0.55}, -1,1}]
```

.

Comment: Please note that `a*x^4+b*x^3+c*x^2+d>0`  when `0 <= a <= .25, 0 <= b < .25, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1`, so we can not plot such region.

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a*x^4 + b*x^3 + c*x^2 + d, {x, -5, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], 
  MeshShading -> {Blue, Green}], {a, -0.25, 0.25}, {b, -0.25, 
  0.25}, {{c, 1}, -1, 1}, {{d, 0.55}, -1, 1}]
```

- Some roots maybe missing when the curves tangent to the x-axis(that is do not cross the x-axis)
- `x` is the root of the equation and `x>0` is ambiguous.